# How to remove a file with Python which is not opened?

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system

Here is the code I am using. When I try to remove the file this exception is thrown:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

The process that the exception is talking about is the same process I am using.
And if I try using `os.close(titulo)` the process gives the exception:

> os.close was expecting an integer.

```
 def audioFun(audio):
            titulo = audio.download()
            clip = mp.VideoFileClip(titulo)
            nombre_audio=titulo.rsplit(".",1)[0]+".mp3"
            r = clip.audio.write_audiofile(nombre_audio)
            os.remove(titulo)
            return nombre_audio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[GitHub.Zulko]: Classes of Video Clips - VideoFileClip](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#videofileclip):

> `close(self)`    [[source]](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/_modules/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.html#VideoFileClip.close)
>
> Close the internal reader.

So, you need to:

```py
# ...

clip.close()  # Close the clip before deleting the file
os.remove(titulo)

# ...
```